# Backup encrypted dmg to dropbox, google drive, box etc

Tags: macos, mac, backup, dropbox

I use an encrypted dmg for my sensitive documents. I don't want to place this dmg in a google drive or dropbox folder because I'm terrified I'd open it on another computer and corrupt the dmg. I have the dmg in my home folder and use Time Machine but I'd like to periodically copy it to gdrive or dropbox for an added level of protection (e.g. my house burns down or theft). I'm wondering if there's an eloquent solution to copy this file to folder X once per day, or ideally, after it changes and is not longer mounted. I could use cron but that gets complicated since the computer may not be on when cron fires.  Perhaps I'm over thinking and there's a better method altogether to accomplish this.

Comment: Manually uploading once a week does it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Well. You may upload files to any ftp or dav (box.com 10gb free ) servers with  immortalfiles.com. You may upload crypted dmg or this good backup tool encrypt files for you.